# why css is not work corectly on vite lib mode?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, vite

I want to create a new npm package and I have a problem with vite lib mode.
I want my package to export some UI components that has some styles, project works fine on `yarn dev` but when I build it the `style.css` file inside `dist` directory is not used anywhere, so the styles not applied to the components

this is my `vite.config.ts` file

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/main.tsx"),
      name: "MyLib",
      fileName: "my-lib",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["react", "react-dom"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "React",
          "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

and this is `dist` folder :

[image]

I know I can import my styles separately like :

```
import Skeleton from "skeleton-sh";
import "skeleton-sh/style";
```

but I want is to just import package like  `import Skeleton from "skeleton-sh";` and its import the styles for me

Comment: For anyone that might need help with this question, I've answered another question that might be helpful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76519546/754707