# React component library built with Vite generates one big style.css, how to split this or have styling injected?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm currently rewriting the build step of our component library to use Vite. I'm running into issues regarding styles and them not being split up, but rather bundled into one big style.css file. This brings me two problems:

- it's not included automatically when I install the package into another project. If I import a component, the `style.css` is not magically imported.
- I'm importing styles of components I'm not actually using.

In my previous setup I had style injection, which meant that the CSS was injected into the component and, therefore, split up. Can I achieve something similar with Vite?

My current build setup is like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), dts()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": "/src"
    }
  },
  build: {
    outDir: "dist",
    lib: {
      entry: "src/index.ts",
      name: "lib",
      fileName: format => `lib.${format}.js`
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["react", "react-dom"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "React",
          "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
        }
      }
    },
    sourcemap: true
  },
  css: {
    modules: {
      generateScopedName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
    }
  }
});
```

And the eventual `dist` folder looks like this (I excluded all of the `.d.ts` files):

[image]

As you can see, there's one big `style.css`, which is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't solved your issue yet, the easiest way that I could find is to add the plugin `vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js` to Vite that internalize the CSS generated into the JS file.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js

You then can change your vite configuration file to:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";
// added the import for inject css automatically...
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from 'vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(), 
    dts(),
    cssInjectedByJsPlugin(),
  ],
  // ... rest of your vite configuration
});
```